# Format of name of a Python package with setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, setup.py

What should be the format of the `name`  argument of `setuptools.setup()`? Is it free-form so I can use spaces on it?

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="My Stuff",
    version="0.0.1.dev1",
    packages=find_packages(),
    test_suite='page_peel_tests'
)
```

Or should it be an identifier?

```
setup(
    name="MyStuff", # Or my_stuff
    version="0.0.1.dev1",
    packages=find_packages(),
    test_suite='page_peel_tests'
)
```

May I use hyphens on it?

```
setup(
    name="my-stuff",
    version="0.0.1.dev1",
    packages=find_packages(),
    test_suite='page_peel_tests'
)
```

Also, are the rules different between setuptools and distutils?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use spaces. Names are case insensitive, hyphens and underscores are equivalent and there are a few other cases of "confusable" characters treated as equivalent. From [PEP 426](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0426/#name) on package naming:

> As distribution names are used as part of URLs, filenames, command
>   line parameters and must also interoperate with other packaging
>   systems, the permitted characters are constrained to:
>
> ```
> ASCII letters ( [a-zA-Z] )
> ASCII digits ( [0-9] )
> underscores ( _ )
> hyphens ( - )
> periods ( . )
> ```
>
> Distribution names MUST start and end with an ASCII letter or digit.

There is no difference in this for setuptools and distutils.

Don't worry about distutils though; **setuptools** is the way to go. Those tumultuous days are over. As of 2013, "setuptools [is] the default choice for packaging". Here are the packaging tool [recommendations](https://packaging.python.org/current/#packaging-tool-recommendations) and, while the links are broken, the footnotes provide solid information on why setuptools is better and Pip will use it for installation anyway.